# Expected value of random variable which is the number of drawns required

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance, expected-value

An urn has n balls and we take balls from it with replacement until each ball has been drawn at least one. X denotes the number of draws required. What is the expected value and variance of X? 
I think X is at least n, is it true? And how should I find the expected value of it?

Comment: This is known as the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem),

Comment: Thank you so much